# JQuery: Finding a way to name cloned input fields

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm not the best at using jQuery, but I do require it to be able to make my website user-friendly.

I have several tables involved in my website, and for each the user should be able to add/delete rows. I created a jquery function, with help from stackoverflow, and it successfully added/deleted rows. Now the only problem with this is the names for those input fields is slightly messed up. I would like each input field to be an array: so like name[0] for the first row, name[1] for the second row, etc. I have a bunch of tables all with different inputs, so how would I make jQuery adjust the names accordingly?

My function, doesn't work completely, but I do not know how to go about changing it.

My Jquery function looks like:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $("body").on('click', '.add_row', function() {
      var tr = $(this).closest('.row').prev('table').find('tr.ia_table:last');
      var clone = tr.clone();
      clone.find("input").val('');
      clone.find("select").val('');

      clone.find('input').each(function(i) {
      $(this).attr('name', $(this).attr('name') + i);
    });

    clone.find('select').each(function(i) {
       $(this).attr('name', $(this).attr('name') + i);
    });

    tr.after(clone);


  });

  $("body").on('click', '.delete_row', function() {
     var rowCount = $(this).closest('.row').prev('table').find('tr.ia_table').length;
     var tr = $(this).closest('.row').prev('table').find('tr.ia_table:last');
     if (rowCount > 1) {
         tr.remove();
     };
  });
});
```

I also created a jsFiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/tareenmj/err73gLL/.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

**UPDATE - Partial Working Solution**

After help from a lot of users, I was able to create a function which does this:

```
$("body").on('click', '.add_row', function() {
            var tr = $(this).closest('.row').prev('table').find('tr.ia_table:last');
            var clone = tr.clone();
            clone.find("input").val('');
            clone.find("select").val('');

            clone.find('input').each(function() {
                var msg=$(this).attr('name');
                var x=parseInt(msg.split('[').pop().split(']').shift());
                var test=msg.substr(0,msg.indexOf('['))+"[";
                x++;
                x=x.toString();
                test=test+x+"]";
                $(this).attr('name', test);

            });

            clone.find('select').each(function() {
                var msg1=$(this).attr('name');
                var x1=parseInt(msg1.split('[').pop().split(']').shift());
                var test1=msg1.substr(0,msg1.indexOf('['))+"[";
                x1++;
                x1=x1.toString();
                test1=test1+x1+"]";
                $(this).attr('name', test1);
            });

            tr.after(clone);

});
```

A working jsFiddle is here: https://jsfiddle.net/tareenmj/amojyjjn/2/

The only problem is that if I do not select any of the options in the select inputs, it doesn't provide me with a value of null, whereas it should. Any tips on fixing this issue?

Comment: If I'm understanding it correctly, in your jsfiddle the expected first name should be `John`, and the second `Mike`? What should happen if there are more rows than names?

Comment: I understand how it can come across, but I adjusted my table to make it more conveyable. In my original table, I have a courses selection, but the user should be able to select the same name for different rows, for my purpose.

Comment: `name[0]` would not be a good `name` or `id` in HTML. The brackets can/will cause problems. Stick to Alpha-Numeric values.

Comment: I see, didn't realize that. How would I change up the cloned row's names from name_0 to name_1 and so on?

Comment: @Muhammad see my answer

Comment: It's probably most beneficial to NOT rename the fields.  Most server-side languages handle a set of same-name input fields as an array, with certain conditions (like in PHP you have to append brackets, eg name='fieldname[]')

Comment: Yea but an array allows me to easily iterate over them from PHP, otherwise with names like name_0, name_1, name_2 etc will be difficult to iterate over. The array bit does work well, for the most part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Full Working Solution for Anyone Who needs it**

So after doing loads and loads of research, I found a very simple way on how to do this. Instead of manually adjusting the name of the array, I realised that the clone method will do it automatically for you if you supply an array as the name. So something like name="name[]" will end up working. The brackets without any text has to be there. Explanation can't possible describe the code fully, so here is the JQuery code required for this behaviour to work:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$("body").on('click', '.add_row', function() {
  var tr = $(this).closest('.row').prev('table').find('tr.ia_table:last');
  var clone = tr.clone();
  clone.find("input").val('');

  tr.after(clone);
});

$("body").on('click', '.delete_row', function() {
   var rowCount = 
   $(this).closest('.row').prev('table').find('tr.ia_table').length;
     var tr = $(this).closest('.row').prev('table').find('tr.ia_table:last');
     if (rowCount > 1) {
       tr.remove();
     };
});
});
```

A fully working JSfiddle is provided here: https://jsfiddle.net/tareenmj/amojyjjn/5/

*Just a tip, that you have to be remove the disabled select since this will not pass a value of null.*

Answer (score 1):

I think I understand your problem. See if this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/err73gLL/2/) works for you...

This is what I did, inside each of the `clone.find()` functions, I added the following logic...

```
clone.find('input').each(function(i) {
    // extract the number part of the name
    number = parseInt($(this).attr('name').substr($(this).attr('name').indexOf("_") + 1));
    // increment the number
    number += 1;
    // extract the name itself (without the row index)
    name = $(this).attr('name').substr(0, $(this).attr('name').indexOf('_'));
    // add the row index to the string
    $(this).attr('name', name + "_" + number);
});
```

In essence, I separate the `name` into 2 parts based on the `_`, the string and the row index. I increment the row index every time the `add_row` is called.

So each row will have something like the following structure when a row is added...

```
 // row 1
 sectionTB1_1
 presentationTB1_1
 percentageTB1_1
 courseTB1_1
 sessionTB1_1
 reqElecTB1_1

 // row 2
 sectionTB1_2
 presentationTB1_2
 percentageTB1_2
 courseTB1_2
 sessionTB1_2
 reqElecTB1_2

 // etc.
```

Let me know if this is what you were looking for.

Comment: @Bolbao I attempted to add this code, after building upon your solution and it's working great but the only problem is that if I leave any select option as blank, it won't submit a value of null. I need the value to be null. I show it on my jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/tareenmj/amojyjjn/2/

Comment: I may be misunderstanding your question, but why can't you add a blank  `<option></option>` and set that as the default value `<option selected="selected">`?

Comment: When I die and dump the results from the form, if I haven't selected any of the select options, it doesn't even appear as null. Yea I tried <option selected=selected"></option> and that doesn't work either. I need to have null values appear.

Comment: so the cloned select options have no value being set to them. You are setting it to blank with this line...`clone.find("select").val('');`...I removed that line and I created a default `blank` value using `<option selected="selected">` (I only did it for the first select option in the example)

Comment: yea I tried both, no luck :/ For some reason disabled seems to remove any value associated with that option.

Comment: So using the second option, what do you see when you dump the results?

Comment: It wasn't even giving a null value. It wasn't posting anything. I figured it out tho, thanks for your help!